# Conditional expectation for a weighted squared random variable

Tags: conditional-expectation

By the law of total expectation, the conditional expected value of *X* given *Y* is given by $$E(X)=E(E(X|Y))$$ Can someone please point me to the theory or identity showing the relation in the case we have the weighted squared shown below $$E(X^TQX)$$ I can easily find the result for the non-conditional case but not for the conditional case.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. You can apply LIE as $E[X'QX]=E[X'E[Q|X]X],$ but is there something else you are specifically looking for?

Comment: I'll try the explain the question further. *X* is a random vector and *Q* is a constant diagonal matrix. While there exist the identity showing that *E(X'QX)=E(X)'QE(X)+tr(Qcov(X))*, I cannot find a similar identity for the case where the random vector X is dependent on the random vector Y.

Comment: Ok, so what exactly do you want? An identity for $E[X'QX|Y]$?

Comment: Yes, though I'm not sure if the expression should be written as $$E[X'QX|Y]$$ or $$E[X'QX]|Y$$

Comment: The second one doesn't make sense. In any case, the identity should be the same, just conditioning on $Y$ wherever there is an expectation.

Comment: I really don't see what this has to do with LIE though in terms of your original question.

Comment: My case is that I have a random vector *X* conditioned on random vector *Y*. For the case of *E(X)* we can write *E(E(X|Y))*. If *X* was a variable instead of a vector, we can write *E(X^2)* conditioned on *Y* is *E(Var[X|Y]+(E(X|Y))^2)*. I'm looking for a similar expression when *X* is a vector and we need to find *E(X'QX)* conditioned on *Y* given *Q* is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: A random vector "conditioned" on another random vector doesn't make sense. A random variable is a function between two sample spaces; what would "$X|Y$" on its own mean? On the other hand, *conditional expectation* does make sense. And the identity you mention for $X$ scalar should be $E[X^2|Y]=\text{Var}(X|Y)+(E[X|Y])^2$

Comment: As mentioned, the identity you are looking for is exactly the same, just conditioning on $Y$, i.e. $E[X'QX|Y]=E[X|Y]'QE[X|Y]+tr(Qcov(X|Y))$

Comment: I got the nomenclature and definitions from the wiki page on [Law of total expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) where they define both X and Y as being random. I'm still not sure if you understood what I'm looking for.... (thanks for the fast replys bdw...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133743/discussion-between-golden-ratio-and-darren-debattista).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the identity you mention in the comments,

$$E[X′QX]=E[X]′QE[X]+\text{tr}(Q\text{cov}(X)),$$

where $Q$ is constant and $\text{cov}(X)$ is the variance-covariance matrix of $X$ can be shown as follows:

First recall that the trace is linear and invariant to cyclic product permutations, i.e.
$$\text{tr}(aA+bB)=a\text{tr}(A)+b\text{tr}(B),\quad a,b \text{ scalar}\\
\text{tr}(ABC)=\text{tr}(BCA)=\text{tr}(CAB).$$

Since $X′QX$ is a scalar and hence equal to its own trace, we have
$$E[X′QX]=E[\text{tr}(X′QX)]=E[\text{tr}(QXX′)]
=\text{tr}(QE[XX′])\\
=\text{tr}(Q(E[XX′]-E[X]E[X]'+E[X]E[X]'))\\
=\text{tr}(Q(\text{cov}(X)+E[X]E[X]'))\\
=\text{tr}(Q\text{cov}(X))+\text{tr}(QE[X]E[X]')\\
=\text{tr}(Q\text{cov}(X))+\text{tr}(E[X]'QE[X])\\
=\text{tr}(Q\text{cov}(X))+E[X]'QE[X].$$

Replacing $E[\cdot]$ with $E[\cdot|Y]$ in the above gives the analogous conditional identity

$$E[X′QX|Y]=\text{tr}(Q\text{cov}(X|Y))+E[X|Y]'QE[X|Y] \quad (1).$$

Finally, as discussed in comments, if you wish to write $E[X′QX]$ in terms of conditional expectations, we have by LIE
$$E[X′QX]=E[E[X′QX|Y]],$$

where the inner expectation is as given in $(1)$.

Comment: Thanks. That explains it nicely!

Comment: @DarrenDeBattista okay great!